# SqlAlchemy session.add() can cause Out of Memory?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, out-of-memory

I have an infinite loop in my python script that looks just like this:

```
while True:
    obj = DatabaseObject(
        row_name_1 = 'name_1',
        row_name_2 = 'name_2'
    )
    session.add(obj)
    try:
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
```

My script needs to constantly insert rows to a database and it all works fine, the problem I'm having is my script being killed by Linux because I'm running out of memory, so can this SqlAlchemy approach be the cause of my script being killed ?

Comment: have you considered that your script is raising an exception and going back again on some kind of invalid connection state an infinite number of times?  squashing the exception like that is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the `obj` for future referencing, then

```
session.expunge(obj)
del obj
```

should logically work.

[`session.expunge_all()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#expunging) could also be used.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about deleting the created object.

Comment: the object is automatically deferenced from the session when you lose references to it.  no need for expunge().